# When creating a filtering rule in outlook, how can I search for a string that includes the " character? Is there an escape character?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

Let's say I'm creating a rule where *if* the first line of the message body is this, I want to move it to a specific folder:

> Someone in your group has moved this to "place".

So as far as I can see, I can look for a string in the body, but having those quotes in there throws a wrench in things. In addition to not knowing how to only look at the first line of the body (no big deal) Here's the sort of stuff that hasn't worked in search, as I don't know about an escape character.

> Someone in your group has moved this to "place".
>
> "Someone in your group has moved this to "place"."
>
> "Someone in your group has moved this to \"place\"."

Comment: Caveat:  Ensure the quotes are in fact double-quotes `"` and not smart (directional) quotes `“` and `”`.

Comment: Consider omitting the quoted word from your search query.  While not exact, it's unlikely other e-mails will start with those exact words.

Comment: Possible [so] duplicate: [Regular Expression Rules in Outlook 2007?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3865500) uses VBA to implement regular expressions in rules.

Comment: to the person saying "omit that part of the query", the part in quotes is the most important part.